# Which SATA drivers to load in Windows System Recover Options on HP Envy h8-1414

Tags: drivers, sata, acronis-trueimage, hp-envy

I just cloned Windows 7 64-bit professional from an existing drive to a new one on an HP Envy h8-1414.  Now I'm at the Windows System Recovery Options screen (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/68942-sata-drivers-load-windows-recovery-options.html) and I want to load a SATA driver so I can load up my old Windows 7 installation.

Where can I get drivers to make this happen?  I tried the HP website with no luck, and then I tried the Gigabyte website because it has a Gigbyte motherboard.   I searched for the motherboard specified on the HP Envy h8-1414 specifications and didn't have much luck...so on the Support & Downloads page I selected Option 1. Search by Product Category and picked "Socket AM3+" and the chipset "AMD 970" and the model number is a mystery I don't know where to find that on the board...so I just picked one at random....but all I get are bios updates and motherboard manuals...no SATA Controller drivers for Windows 7 64-bit...what gives?  Where can I find these drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the details you provided, this should place you in the right path.
please let us know some feedback.

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/raid_windows.aspx#2

**note**: you may have to run the setup but only let is extract the files. then find the f6 folder inside the extracted results. should be easy to find as usually it is named "F6"

Comment: Yeah I found the drivers they appear to work...now I just have to get the dang machine to boot.